# How to call a URL using trigger?

Tags: integration, custom-button, url

I have a custom button(Create Ticket) on a custom object (Deal) which has link/URL as

```
https://jira-staging.companyname.com/plugins/servlet/create-issue?crmtoken=XXXX&id=Deal__c:{!Deal__c.Id}
```

that redirects the user to a screen which creates a Jira ticket.

Is there any way I can hit this URL without the button ex. using trigger/flow? I want to create a Jira Ticket on Deal record creation.

Thanks.

Comment: You should never include API tokens in your post. I've removed it here.

Comment: Thanks. It was a fake token. But, for future, I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a trigger on a Deal object (since you need a Deal Id, use after insert trigger) and then call an API method by using asynchronous Apex.

For example, a @future(callout=true) method. There is a limitation of 100 callouts per transaction. So you need to split your trigger transaction (200 records max) into 2 chunks by 100.

You can also use Queueable class and implement Database.AllowsCallouts interface. Pass all trigger records into queueable and then make callouts for the first 100 and then chain queueable for the rest of the records.